# How to export/read data from async function that's querying firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, promise

Learning how to use react by creating a project.

I am trying to filter the data by when it was added into the collection. Then I am trying to add all the **totalCalories** in a certain amount of time so i can display it in form using react.

However, I do not know how to get the values for **totalCalories** and also get the other fields like mealTime. I want to display all of them in my **app.js** However when i do i get undefined, or says promise pending.

Any help would be massively appreciated. **Thanks**

**firebase.js**

```
    export async function run() {
      const time = 48;
      const timediff = moment(new Date()).subtract(time, "hours")._d;
      await db
        .collection("/food/meals")
        .where("mealTime", ">=", timediff)
        .get()
        .then((qSnapshot) => {
          let totalCalories = 0;
          qSnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            totalCalories += doc.data().calories;
            console.log(doc.id, " -> ", doc.data());
          });
          console.log(totalCalories);
          return totalCalories;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
    }
    
    run(); //returns nothing 
    console.log(run()); //Promise {<pending>}
    
    console.log(run().totalCalories); //undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Instead of :

```
await db...
```

=>

```
return db...
```

run doesn't need to be an async function anymore

```
run().then(totalCalories => console.log('totalCalories :', totalCalories));
```

Now run return a promise, when this promise is resolved it return the totalCalories returned by your db query

Full code :

```
function run() {
    const time = 48;
    const timediff = moment(new Date()).subtract(time, "hours")._d;
    return db // this is returned by the function (as a promise)
      .collection("/food/meals")
      .where("mealTime", ">=", timediff)
      .get()
      .then((qSnapshot) => {
        let totalCalories = 0;
        qSnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          totalCalories += doc.data().calories;
          console.log(doc.id, " -> ", doc.data());
        });
        console.log(totalCalories);
        return totalCalories; //this is returned by db query
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
  }

// if your code is an ES6 module
let result = await run(); 
console.log('Result :', result);

// else
run().then(result => console.log('Total : ', result));

// to export this as ES6 Module
export { run }
// or
export default run;
```

To return all the data + calculated value totalCalories you can do :

```
return { ...doc.data(),  'totalCalories': totalCalories };
```

Comment: i get 'totalCalories : undefined' after the changes- it still console log everything within run() tho

Comment: Try with my edits, if it doesn't solve the probleme we'll try to debug ;) Unfortunately, I can't try the code by my own

Comment: first "'result' is assigned a value but never used." and second broke everything due to:  "Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Cannot use keyword 'await'"

Comment: second error probably mean you are not on top of a module / async function, first one must ba a simple warning due to the fact you don't log the result (edited)

Comment: comment the solution using await and try with run.then()....

Comment: great, that worked- but only issue is now- i want to get other fields too from the data in that query like mealTime which i want to show to the user. How do i do that if i am only returning totalCalories

Comment: I added the answer at the end of the post, It works only if doc.data() is an object, which it looks to be ;)